# How to access button under DataTemplate via code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have got this code and I need to access somehow `Button`  and call its `Command`.

How it could be done?

Thank you!

```
<DataTemplate> 
 <Grid>
   <Button  Command="someexternalcontrol:ContentControl1.RotateCommand" Content="Flip"  Visibility="Visible" Height="5" Width="5" />
 </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer the link below . Hope it was helpful.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/fb16c929-7318-41de-9ef4-fb62cb1bb45f